# Static linking of Boost and OpenCV libs with Eclipse CDR. errors

Tags: c++, boost, opencv, eclipse-cdt, static-linking

I try to link my project statically with the Boost and OpenCV libs in Eclipse CDT.  I have searched Google which libraries I have to add and added them to the linker. But the error messages are still there. What am I doing wrong?

```
make all 
Building target: CalibServer
Invoking: GCC C++ Linker
g++ -L/usr/local/lib64 -static -o"CalibServer"  ./src/CalibServer.o   -lhighgui -lz -lrt -ltiff -ljpeg -lpng12 -lpthread -lcv -lboost_iostreams -lboost_date_time -lboost_regex -lcxcore -lcvaux -lboost_thread -lboost_filesystem
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.4.5/../../../../lib/libhighgui.a(loadsave.o): In function `cv::imdecode_(cv::Mat const&, int, int, cv::Mat*)':
(.text._ZN2cvL9imdecode_ERKNS_3MatEiiPS0_+0x1db): warning: the use of `tmpnam' is dangerous, better use `mkstemp'
./src/CalibServer.o: In function `__static_initialization_and_destruction_0':
/usr/include/boost/system/error_code.hpp:208: undefined reference to `boost::system::get_system_category()'
/usr/include/boost/system/error_code.hpp:209: undefined reference to `boost::system::get_generic_category()'
/usr/include/boost/system/error_code.hpp:214: undefined reference to `boost::system::get_generic_category()'
/usr/include/boost/system/error_code.hpp:215: undefined reference to `boost::system::get_generic_category()'
/usr/include/boost/system/error_code.hpp:216: undefined reference to `boost::system::get_system_category()'
./src/CalibServer.o: In function `error_code':
/usr/include/boost/system/error_code.hpp:315: undefined reference to `boost::system::get_system_category()'
./src/CalibServer.o: In function `boost::asio::error::get_system_category()':
/usr/include/boost/asio/error.hpp:218: undefined reference to `boost::system::get_system_category()'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.4.5/../../../../lib/libhighgui.a(grfmt_jpeg2000.o): In function `global constructors keyed to _ZN2cv13Jpeg2KDecoderC2Ev':
(.text._GLOBAL__I__ZN2cv13Jpeg2KDecoderC2Ev+0x5): undefined reference to `jas_init'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.4.5/../../../../lib/libhighgui.a(grfmt_jpeg2000.o): In function `cv::JasperInitializer::~JasperInitializer()':
(.text._ZN2cv17JasperInitializerD1Ev[cv::JasperInitializer::~JasperInitializer()]+0x1): undefined reference to `jas_cleanup'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.4.5/../../../../lib/libhighgui.a(grfmt_jpeg2000.o): In function `cv::Jpeg2KEncoder::writeComponent16u(void*, cv::Mat const&)':
(.text._ZN2cv13Jpeg2KEncoder17writeComponent16uEPvRKNS_3MatE+0x3d): undefined reference to `jas_matrix_create'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.4.5/../../../../lib/libhighgui.a(grfmt_jpeg2000.o): In function `cv::Jpeg2KEncoder::writeComponent16u(void*, cv::Mat const&)':
(.text._ZN2cv13Jpeg2KEncoder17writeComponent16uEPvRKNS_3MatE+0x10a): undefined reference to `jas_image_writecmpt'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.4.5/../../../../lib/libhighgui.a(grfmt_jpeg2000.o): In function `cv::Jpeg2KEncoder::writeComponent16u(void*, cv::Mat const&)':
(.text._ZN2cv13Jpeg2KEncoder17writeComponent16uEPvRKNS_3MatE+0x136): undefined reference to `jas_matrix_destroy'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.4.5/../../../../lib/libhighgui.a(grfmt_jpeg2000.o): In function `cv::Jpeg2KEncoder::writeComponent8u(void*, cv::Mat const&)':
(.text._ZN2cv13Jpeg2KEncoder16writeComponent8uEPvRKNS_3MatE+0x3d): undefined reference to `jas_matrix_create'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.4.5/../../../../lib/libhighgui.a(grfmt_jpeg2000.o): In function `cv::Jpeg2KEncoder::writeComponent8u(void*, cv::Mat const&)':
(.text._ZN2cv13Jpeg2KEncoder16writeComponent8uEPvRKNS_3MatE+0x10a): undefined reference to `jas_image_writecmpt'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.4.5/../../../../lib/libhighgui.a(grfmt_jpeg2000.o): In function `cv::Jpeg2KEncoder::writeComponent8u(void*, cv::Mat const&)':
(.text._ZN2cv13Jpeg2KEncoder16writeComponent8uEPvRKNS_3MatE+0x136): undefined reference to `jas_matrix_destroy'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.4.5/../../../../lib/libhighgui.a(grfmt_jpeg2000.o): In function `cv::Jpeg2KDecoder::close()':
(.text._ZN2cv13Jpeg2KDecoder5closeEv+0xe): undefined reference to `jas_stream_close'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.4.5/../../../../lib/libhighgui.a(grfmt_jpeg2000.o): In function `cv::Jpeg2KDecoder::close()':
(.text._ZN2cv13Jpeg2KDecoder5closeEv+0x24): undefined reference to `jas_image_destroy'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.4.5/../../../../lib/libhighgui.a(grfmt_jpeg2000.o): In function `cv::Jpeg2KDecoder::readData(cv::Mat&)':
(.text._ZN2cv13Jpeg2KDecoder8readDataERNS_3MatE+0x87): undefined reference to `jas_image_getcmptbytype'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.4.5/../../../../lib/libhighgui.a(grfmt_jpeg2000.o): In function `cv::Jpeg2KDecoder::readData(cv::Mat&)':
(.text._ZN2cv13Jpeg2KDecoder8readDataERNS_3MatE+0x9b): undefined reference to `jas_image_getcmptbytype'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.4.5/../../../../lib/libhighgui.a(grfmt_jpeg2000.o): In function `cv::Jpeg2KDecoder::readData(cv::Mat&)':
(.text._ZN2cv13Jpeg2KDecoder8readDataERNS_3MatE+0xab): undefined reference to `jas_image_getcmptbytype'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.4.5/../../../../lib/libhighgui.a(grfmt_jpeg2000.o): In function `cv::Jpeg2KDecoder::readData(cv::Mat&)':
(.text._ZN2cv13Jpeg2KDecoder8readDataERNS_3MatE+0x12f): undefined reference to `jas_matrix_destroy'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.4.5/../../../../lib/libhighgui.a(grfmt_jpeg2000.o): In function `cv::Jpeg2KDecoder::readData(cv::Mat&)':
(.text._ZN2cv13Jpeg2KDecoder8readDataERNS_3MatE+0x1ad): undefined reference to `jas_matrix_create'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.4.5/../../../../lib/libhighgui.a(grfmt_jpeg2000.o): In function `cv::Jpeg2KDecoder::readData(cv::Mat&)':
(.text._ZN2cv13Jpeg2KDecoder8readDataERNS_3MatE+0x1d4): undefined reference to `jas_image_readcmpt'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.4.5/../../../../lib/libhighgui.a(grfmt_jpeg2000.o): In function `cv::Jpeg2KDecoder::readData(cv::Mat&)':
(.text._ZN2cv13Jpeg2KDecoder8readDataERNS_3MatE+0x267): undefined reference to `jas_stream_close'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.4.5/../../../../lib/libhighgui.a(grfmt_jpeg2000.o): In function `cv::Jpeg2KDecoder::readData(cv::Mat&)':
(.text._ZN2cv13Jpeg2KDecoder8readDataERNS_3MatE+0x27d): undefined reference to `jas_image_destroy'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.4.5/../../../../lib/libhighgui.a(grfmt_jpeg2000.o): In function `cv::Jpeg2KDecoder::readData(cv::Mat&)':
(.text._ZN2cv13Jpeg2KDecoder8readDataERNS_3MatE+0x2b8): undefined reference to `jas_cmprof_createfromclrspc'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.4.5/../../../../lib/libhighgui.a(grfmt_jpeg2000.o): In function `cv::Jpeg2KDecoder::readData(cv::Mat&)':
(.text._ZN2cv13Jpeg2KDecoder8readDataERNS_3MatE+0x2d4): undefined reference to `jas_image_chclrspc'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.4.5/../../../../lib/libhighgui.a(grfmt_jpeg2000.o): In function `cv::Jpeg2KDecoder::readData(cv::Mat&)':
(.text._ZN2cv13Jpeg2KDecoder8readDataERNS_3MatE+0x2e7): undefined reference to `jas_image_destroy'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.4.5/../../../../lib/libhighgui.a(grfmt_jpeg2000.o): In function `cv::Jpeg2KDecoder::readData(cv::Mat&)':
(.text._ZN2cv13Jpeg2KDecoder8readDataERNS_3MatE+0x2f3): undefined reference to `jas_cmprof_destroy'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.4.5/../../../../lib/libhighgui.a(grfmt_jpeg2000.o): In function `cv::Jpeg2KDecoder::readData(cv::Mat&)':
(.text._ZN2cv13Jpeg2KDecoder8readDataERNS_3MatE+0x305): undefined reference to `jas_image_getcmptbytype'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.4.5/../../../../lib/libhighgui.a(grfmt_jpeg2000.o): In function `cv::Jpeg2KDecoder::readData(cv::Mat&)':
(.text._ZN2cv13Jpeg2KDecoder8readDataERNS_3MatE+0x35a): undefined reference to `jas_cmprof_destroy'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.4.5/../../../../lib/libhighgui.a(grfmt_jpeg2000.o): In function `cv::Jpeg2KDecoder::readHeader()':
(.text._ZN2cv13Jpeg2KDecoder10readHeaderEv+0xe): undefined reference to `jas_stream_close'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.4.5/../../../../lib/libhighgui.a(grfmt_jpeg2000.o): In function `cv::Jpeg2KDecoder::readHeader()':
(.text._ZN2cv13Jpeg2KDecoder10readHeaderEv+0x24): undefined reference to `jas_image_destroy'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.4.5/../../../../lib/libhighgui.a(grfmt_jpeg2000.o): In function `cv::Jpeg2KDecoder::readHeader()':
(.text._ZN2cv13Jpeg2KDecoder10readHeaderEv+0x3a): undefined reference to `jas_stream_fopen'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.4.5/../../../../lib/libhighgui.a(grfmt_jpeg2000.o): In function `cv::Jpeg2KDecoder::readHeader()':
(.text._ZN2cv13Jpeg2KDecoder10readHeaderEv+0x56): undefined reference to `jas_image_decode'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.4.5/../../../../lib/libhighgui.a(grfmt_jpeg2000.o): In function `cv::Jpeg2KDecoder::readHeader()':
(.text._ZN2cv13Jpeg2KDecoder10readHeaderEv+0xfb): undefined reference to `jas_stream_close'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.4.5/../../../../lib/libhighgui.a(grfmt_jpeg2000.o): In function `cv::Jpeg2KDecoder::readHeader()':
(.text._ZN2cv13Jpeg2KDecoder10readHeaderEv+0x113): undefined reference to `jas_image_destroy'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.4.5/../../../../lib/libhighgui.a(grfmt_jpeg2000.o): In function `cv::Jpeg2KEncoder::write(cv::Mat const&, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > const&)':
(.text._ZN2cv13Jpeg2KEncoder5writeERKNS_3MatERKSt6vectorIiSaIiEE+0xc2): undefined reference to `jas_image_create'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.4.5/../../../../lib/libhighgui.a(grfmt_jpeg2000.o): In function `cv::Jpeg2KEncoder::write(cv::Mat const&, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > const&)':
(.text._ZN2cv13Jpeg2KEncoder5writeERKNS_3MatERKSt6vectorIiSaIiEE+0x13e): undefined reference to `jas_matrix_create'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.4.5/../../../../lib/libhighgui.a(grfmt_jpeg2000.o): In function `cv::Jpeg2KEncoder::write(cv::Mat const&, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > const&)':
(.text._ZN2cv13Jpeg2KEncoder5writeERKNS_3MatERKSt6vectorIiSaIiEE+0x20a): undefined reference to `jas_image_writecmpt'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.4.5/../../../../lib/libhighgui.a(grfmt_jpeg2000.o): In function `cv::Jpeg2KEncoder::write(cv::Mat const&, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > const&)':
(.text._ZN2cv13Jpeg2KEncoder5writeERKNS_3MatERKSt6vectorIiSaIiEE+0x23b): undefined reference to `jas_matrix_destroy'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.4.5/../../../../lib/libhighgui.a(grfmt_jpeg2000.o): In function `cv::Jpeg2KEncoder::write(cv::Mat const&, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > const&)':
(.text._ZN2cv13Jpeg2KEncoder5writeERKNS_3MatERKSt6vectorIiSaIiEE+0x24e): undefined reference to `jas_stream_fopen'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.4.5/../../../../lib/libhighgui.a(grfmt_jpeg2000.o): In function `cv::Jpeg2KEncoder::write(cv::Mat const&, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > const&)':
(.text._ZN2cv13Jpeg2KEncoder5writeERKNS_3MatERKSt6vectorIiSaIiEE+0x260): undefined reference to `jas_image_strtofmt'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.4.5/../../../../lib/libhighgui.a(grfmt_jpeg2000.o): In function `cv::Jpeg2KEncoder::write(cv::Mat const&, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > const&)':
(.text._ZN2cv13Jpeg2KEncoder5writeERKNS_3MatERKSt6vectorIiSaIiEE+0x274): undefined reference to `jas_image_encode'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.4.5/../../../../lib/libhighgui.a(grfmt_jpeg2000.o): In function `cv::Jpeg2KEncoder::write(cv::Mat const&, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > const&)':
(.text._ZN2cv13Jpeg2KEncoder5writeERKNS_3MatERKSt6vectorIiSaIiEE+0x282): undefined reference to `jas_stream_close'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.4.5/../../../../lib/libhighgui.a(grfmt_jpeg2000.o): In function `cv::Jpeg2KEncoder::write(cv::Mat const&, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > const&)':
(.text._ZN2cv13Jpeg2KEncoder5writeERKNS_3MatERKSt6vectorIiSaIiEE+0x28c): undefined reference to `jas_image_destroy'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.4.5/../../../../lib/libhighgui.a(grfmt_jpeg2000.o): In function `cv::Jpeg2KEncoder::write(cv::Mat const&, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > const&)':
(.text._ZN2cv13Jpeg2KEncoder5writeERKNS_3MatERKSt6vectorIiSaIiEE+0x2e8): undefined reference to `jas_matrix_create'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.4.5/../../../../lib/libhighgui.a(grfmt_jpeg2000.o): In function `cv::Jpeg2KEncoder::write(cv::Mat const&, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > const&)':
(.text._ZN2cv13Jpeg2KEncoder5writeERKNS_3MatERKSt6vectorIiSaIiEE+0x3aa): undefined reference to `jas_image_writecmpt'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.4.5/../../../../lib/libtiff.a(tif_pixarlog.o): In function `PixarLogVSetField':
(.text+0x8f7): undefined reference to `deflateParams'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.4.5/../../../../lib/libtiff.a(tif_pixarlog.o): In function `PixarLogCleanup':
(.text+0xa1c): undefined reference to `inflateEnd'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.4.5/../../../../lib/libtiff.a(tif_pixarlog.o): In function `PixarLogCleanup':
(.text+0xa2d): undefined reference to `deflateEnd'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.4.5/../../../../lib/libtiff.a(tif_pixarlog.o): In function `PixarLogPostEncode':
(.text+0xa81): undefined reference to `deflate'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.4.5/../../../../lib/libtiff.a(tif_pixarlog.o): In function `PixarLogEncode':
(.text+0x11ec): undefined reference to `deflate'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.4.5/../../../../lib/libtiff.a(tif_pixarlog.o): In function `PixarLogPreEncode':
(.text+0x25af): undefined reference to `deflateReset'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.4.5/../../../../lib/libtiff.a(tif_pixarlog.o): In function `PixarLogSetupEncode':
(.text+0x268b): undefined reference to `deflateInit_'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.4.5/../../../../lib/libtiff.a(tif_pixarlog.o): In function `PixarLogDecode':
(.text+0x2823): undefined reference to `inflate'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.4.5/../../../../lib/libtiff.a(tif_pixarlog.o): In function `PixarLogDecode':
(.text+0x2e9d): undefined reference to `inflateSync'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.4.5/../../../../lib/libtiff.a(tif_pixarlog.o): In function `PixarLogPreDecode':
(.text+0x3a0c): undefined reference to `inflateReset'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.4.5/../../../../lib/libtiff.a(tif_pixarlog.o): In function `PixarLogSetupDecode':
(.text+0x3af5): undefined reference to `inflateInit_'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.4.5/../../../../lib/libtiff.a(tif_zip.o): In function `ZIPCleanup':
(.text+0x285): undefined reference to `inflateEnd'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.4.5/../../../../lib/libtiff.a(tif_zip.o): In function `ZIPCleanup':
(.text+0x29d): undefined reference to `deflateEnd'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.4.5/../../../../lib/libtiff.a(tif_zip.o): In function `ZIPEncode':
(.text+0x318): undefined reference to `deflate'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.4.5/../../../../lib/libtiff.a(tif_zip.o): In function `ZIPPostEncode':
(.text+0x401): undefined reference to `deflate'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.4.5/../../../../lib/libtiff.a(tif_zip.o): In function `ZIPPreEncode':
(.text+0x4e3): undefined reference to `deflateReset'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.4.5/../../../../lib/libtiff.a(tif_zip.o): In function `ZIPSetupEncode':
(.text+0x557): undefined reference to `deflateInit_'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.4.5/../../../../lib/libtiff.a(tif_zip.o): In function `ZIPSetupEncode':
(.text+0x584): undefined reference to `inflateEnd'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.4.5/../../../../lib/libtiff.a(tif_zip.o): In function `ZIPDecode':
(.text+0x61e): undefined reference to `inflate'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.4.5/../../../../lib/libtiff.a(tif_zip.o): In function `ZIPDecode':
(.text+0x67e): undefined reference to `inflateSync'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.4.5/../../../../lib/libtiff.a(tif_zip.o): In function `ZIPPreDecode':
(.text+0x778): undefined reference to `inflateReset'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.4.5/../../../../lib/libtiff.a(tif_zip.o): In function `ZIPSetupDecode':
(.text+0x7f1): undefined reference to `inflateInit_'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.4.5/../../../../lib/libtiff.a(tif_zip.o): In function `ZIPSetupDecode':
(.text+0x824): undefined reference to `deflateEnd'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.4.5/../../../../lib/libtiff.a(tif_zip.o): In function `ZIPVSetField':
(.text+0x8f7): undefined reference to `deflateParams'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.4.5/../../../../lib/libpng12.a(libpng12_la-png.o): In function `png_calculate_crc':
(.text+0x1229): undefined reference to `crc32'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.4.5/../../../../lib/libpng12.a(libpng12_la-png.o): In function `png_reset_crc':
(.text+0x125b): undefined reference to `crc32'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.4.5/../../../../lib/libpng12.a(libpng12_la-png.o): In function `png_reset_zstream':
(.text+0x7dd): undefined reference to `inflateReset'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.4.5/../../../../lib/libpng12.a(libpng12_la-pngread.o): In function `png_read_destroy':
(.text+0x23e): undefined reference to `inflateEnd'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.4.5/../../../../lib/libpng12.a(libpng12_la-pngread.o): In function `png_read_row':
(.text+0xa09): undefined reference to `inflate'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.4.5/../../../../lib/libpng12.a(libpng12_la-pngread.o): In function `png_read_init_3':
(.text+0x199e): undefined reference to `inflateInit_'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.4.5/../../../../lib/libpng12.a(libpng12_la-pngread.o): In function `png_create_read_struct_2':
(.text+0x1e84): undefined reference to `inflateInit_'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.4.5/../../../../lib/libpng12.a(libpng12_la-pngwrite.o): In function `png_write_destroy':
(.text+0x763): undefined reference to `deflateEnd'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.4.5/../../../../lib/libpng12.a(libpng12_la-pngwrite.o): In function `png_write_flush':
(.text+0x9e6): undefined reference to `deflate'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.4.5/../../../../lib/libpng12.a(libpng12_la-pngrutil.o): In function `png_inflate':
(.text+0x11f8): undefined reference to `inflate'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.4.5/../../../../lib/libpng12.a(libpng12_la-pngrutil.o): In function `png_inflate':
(.text+0x123c): undefined reference to `inflateReset'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.4.5/../../../../lib/libpng12.a(libpng12_la-pngrutil.o): In function `png_read_finish_row':
(.text+0x18b9): undefined reference to `inflate'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.4.5/../../../../lib/libpng12.a(libpng12_la-pngrutil.o): In function `png_read_finish_row':
(.text+0x1a34): undefined reference to `inflateReset'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.4.5/../../../../lib/libpng12.a(libpng12_la-pngwutil.o): In function `png_text_compress':
(.text+0x6f4): undefined reference to `deflate'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.4.5/../../../../lib/libpng12.a(libpng12_la-pngwutil.o): In function `png_text_compress':
(.text+0x7ba): undefined reference to `deflate'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.4.5/../../../../lib/libpng12.a(libpng12_la-pngwutil.o): In function `png_write_compressed_data_out':
(.text+0xe54): undefined reference to `deflateReset'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.4.5/../../../../lib/libpng12.a(libpng12_la-pngwutil.o): In function `png_write_finish_row':
(.text+0x2a29): undefined reference to `deflate'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.4.5/../../../../lib/libpng12.a(libpng12_la-pngwutil.o): In function `png_write_finish_row':
(.text+0x2a92): undefined reference to `deflateReset'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.4.5/../../../../lib/libpng12.a(libpng12_la-pngwutil.o): In function `png_write_filtered_row':
(.text+0x2c92): undefined reference to `deflate'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.4.5/../../../../lib/libpng12.a(libpng12_la-pngwutil.o): In function `png_write_IHDR':
(.text+0x3ec8): undefined reference to `deflateInit2_'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.4.5/../../../../lib/libcxcore.a(cxsystem.o): In function `cv::getTickCount()':
(.text._ZN2cv12getTickCountEv+0xd): undefined reference to `clock_gettime'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.4.5/../../../../lib/libcxcore.a(cxsystem.o): In function `cvGetTickCount':
(.text.cvGetTickCount+0xd): undefined reference to `clock_gettime'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.4.5/../../../../lib/libcxcore.a(cxlapack.o): In function `cv::determinant(cv::Mat const&)':
(.text._ZN2cv11determinantERKNS_3MatE+0x38a): undefined reference to `dgetrf_'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.4.5/../../../../lib/libcxcore.a(cxlapack.o): In function `cv::determinant(cv::Mat const&)':
(.text._ZN2cv11determinantERKNS_3MatE+0x569): undefined reference to `sgetrf_'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.4.5/../../../../lib/libcxcore.a(cxlapack.o): In function `cv::eigen(cv::Mat const&, cv::Mat&, cv::Mat&, bool, int, int)':
(.text._ZN2cvL5eigenERKNS_3MatERS0_S3_bii+0x667): undefined reference to `dsyevr_'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.4.5/../../../../lib/libcxcore.a(cxlapack.o): In function `cv::eigen(cv::Mat const&, cv::Mat&, cv::Mat&, bool, int, int)':
(.text._ZN2cvL5eigenERKNS_3MatERS0_S3_bii+0x915): undefined reference to `dsyevr_'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.4.5/../../../../lib/libcxcore.a(cxlapack.o): In function `cv::eigen(cv::Mat const&, cv::Mat&, cv::Mat&, bool, int, int)':
(.text._ZN2cvL5eigenERKNS_3MatERS0_S3_bii+0xbf6): undefined reference to `ssyevr_'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.4.5/../../../../lib/libcxcore.a(cxlapack.o): In function `cv::eigen(cv::Mat const&, cv::Mat&, cv::Mat&, bool, int, int)':
(.text._ZN2cvL5eigenERKNS_3MatERS0_S3_bii+0xe7e): undefined reference to `ssyevr_'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.4.5/../../../../lib/libcxcore.a(cxlapack.o): In function `cv::SVD::operator()(cv::Mat const&, int)':
(.text._ZN2cv3SVDclERKNS_3MatEi+0x339): undefined reference to `dgesdd_'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.4.5/../../../../lib/libcxcore.a(cxlapack.o): In function `cv::SVD::operator()(cv::Mat const&, int)':
(.text._ZN2cv3SVDclERKNS_3MatEi+0x571): undefined reference to `dgesdd_'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.4.5/../../../../lib/libcxcore.a(cxlapack.o): In function `cv::SVD::operator()(cv::Mat const&, int)':
(.text._ZN2cv3SVDclERKNS_3MatEi+0x7dd): undefined reference to `sgesdd_'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.4.5/../../../../lib/libcxcore.a(cxlapack.o): In function `cv::SVD::operator()(cv::Mat const&, int)':
(.text._ZN2cv3SVDclERKNS_3MatEi+0xc30): undefined reference to `sgesdd_'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.4.5/../../../../lib/libcxcore.a(cxlapack.o): In function `cv::invert(cv::Mat const&, cv::Mat&, int)':
(.text._ZN2cv6invertERKNS_3MatERS0_i+0x771): undefined reference to `dgetri_'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.4.5/../../../../lib/libcxcore.a(cxlapack.o): In function `cv::invert(cv::Mat const&, cv::Mat&, int)':
(.text._ZN2cv6invertERKNS_3MatERS0_i+0x811): undefined reference to `dgetrf_'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.4.5/../../../../lib/libcxcore.a(cxlapack.o): In function `cv::invert(cv::Mat const&, cv::Mat&, int)':
(.text._ZN2cv6invertERKNS_3MatERS0_i+0xa71): undefined reference to `dpotrf_'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.4.5/../../../../lib/libcxcore.a(cxlapack.o): In function `cv::invert(cv::Mat const&, cv::Mat&, int)':
(.text._ZN2cv6invertERKNS_3MatERS0_i+0xaf3): undefined reference to `sgetri_'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.4.5/../../../../lib/libcxcore.a(cxlapack.o): In function `cv::invert(cv::Mat const&, cv::Mat&, int)':
(.text._ZN2cv6invertERKNS_3MatERS0_i+0xe80): undefined reference to `sgetrf_'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.4.5/../../../../lib/libcxcore.a(cxlapack.o): In function `cv::invert(cv::Mat const&, cv::Mat&, int)':
(.text._ZN2cv6invertERKNS_3MatERS0_i+0xec4): undefined reference to `sgetri_'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.4.5/../../../../lib/libcxcore.a(cxlapack.o): In function `cv::invert(cv::Mat const&, cv::Mat&, int)':
(.text._ZN2cv6invertERKNS_3MatERS0_i+0xf35): undefined reference to `dgetri_'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.4.5/../../../../lib/libcxcore.a(cxlapack.o): In function `cv::invert(cv::Mat const&, cv::Mat&, int)':
(.text._ZN2cv6invertERKNS_3MatERS0_i+0xf6c): undefined reference to `spotrf_'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.4.5/../../../../lib/libcxcore.a(cxlapack.o): In function `cv::invert(cv::Mat const&, cv::Mat&, int)':
(.text._ZN2cv6invertERKNS_3MatERS0_i+0xf92): undefined reference to `spotri_'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.4.5/../../../../lib/libcxcore.a(cxlapack.o): In function `cv::invert(cv::Mat const&, cv::Mat&, int)':
(.text._ZN2cv6invertERKNS_3MatERS0_i+0xfac): undefined reference to `dpotri_'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.4.5/../../../../lib/libcxcore.a(cxlapack.o): In function `cv::solve(cv::Mat const&, cv::Mat const&, cv::Mat&, int)':
(.text._ZN2cv5solveERKNS_3MatES2_RS0_i+0xc04): undefined reference to `dgelsd_'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.4.5/../../../../lib/libcxcore.a(cxlapack.o): In function `cv::solve(cv::Mat const&, cv::Mat const&, cv::Mat&, int)':
(.text._ZN2cv5solveERKNS_3MatES2_RS0_i+0xc95): undefined reference to `spotrf_'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.4.5/../../../../lib/libcxcore.a(cxlapack.o): In function `cv::solve(cv::Mat const&, cv::Mat const&, cv::Mat&, int)':
(.text._ZN2cv5solveERKNS_3MatES2_RS0_i+0x131e): undefined reference to `dgelsd_'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.4.5/../../../../lib/libcxcore.a(cxlapack.o): In function `cv::solve(cv::Mat const&, cv::Mat const&, cv::Mat&, int)':
(.text._ZN2cv5solveERKNS_3MatES2_RS0_i+0x1717): undefined reference to `dgels_'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.4.5/../../../../lib/libcxcore.a(cxlapack.o): In function `cv::solve(cv::Mat const&, cv::Mat const&, cv::Mat&, int)':
(.text._ZN2cv5solveERKNS_3MatES2_RS0_i+0x179b): undefined reference to `dgels_'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.4.5/../../../../lib/libcxcore.a(cxlapack.o): In function `cv::solve(cv::Mat const&, cv::Mat const&, cv::Mat&, int)':
(.text._ZN2cv5solveERKNS_3MatES2_RS0_i+0x180b): undefined reference to `dgesv_'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.4.5/../../../../lib/libcxcore.a(cxlapack.o): In function `cv::solve(cv::Mat const&, cv::Mat const&, cv::Mat&, int)':
(.text._ZN2cv5solveERKNS_3MatES2_RS0_i+0x1854): undefined reference to `dpotrf_'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.4.5/../../../../lib/libcxcore.a(cxlapack.o): In function `cv::solve(cv::Mat const&, cv::Mat const&, cv::Mat&, int)':
(.text._ZN2cv5solveERKNS_3MatES2_RS0_i+0x189c): undefined reference to `dpotrs_'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.4.5/../../../../lib/libcxcore.a(cxlapack.o): In function `cv::solve(cv::Mat const&, cv::Mat const&, cv::Mat&, int)':
(.text._ZN2cv5solveERKNS_3MatES2_RS0_i+0x1950): undefined reference to `sgelsd_'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.4.5/../../../../lib/libcxcore.a(cxlapack.o): In function `cv::solve(cv::Mat const&, cv::Mat const&, cv::Mat&, int)':
(.text._ZN2cv5solveERKNS_3MatES2_RS0_i+0x19f9): undefined reference to `sgelsd_'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.4.5/../../../../lib/libcxcore.a(cxlapack.o): In function `cv::solve(cv::Mat const&, cv::Mat const&, cv::Mat&, int)':
(.text._ZN2cv5solveERKNS_3MatES2_RS0_i+0x1afe): undefined reference to `sgels_'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.4.5/../../../../lib/libcxcore.a(cxlapack.o): In function `cv::solve(cv::Mat const&, cv::Mat const&, cv::Mat&, int)':
(.text._ZN2cv5solveERKNS_3MatES2_RS0_i+0x1b82): undefined reference to `sgels_'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.4.5/../../../../lib/libcxcore.a(cxlapack.o): In function `cv::solve(cv::Mat const&, cv::Mat const&, cv::Mat&, int)':
(.text._ZN2cv5solveERKNS_3MatES2_RS0_i+0x1d27): undefined reference to `spotrs_'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.4.5/../../../../lib/libcxcore.a(cxlapack.o): In function `cv::solve(cv::Mat const&, cv::Mat const&, cv::Mat&, int)':
(.text._ZN2cv5solveERKNS_3MatES2_RS0_i+0x1d72): undefined reference to `sgesv_'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [CalibServer] Error 1
```

Comment: have you tried with 'boost_system' at the end of your boost libs list ?

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned above,the error:

```
/usr/include/boost/system/error_code.hpp:208: undefined reference to boost::system::get_system_category()'
```

...
is because you have not told the linker to link boost_system library, add "-lboost_system" to your linker.

The error:

```
(.text._ZN2cv13Jpeg2KEncoder17writeComponent16uEPvRKNS_3MatE+0x3d): undefined reference to `jas_matrix_create'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.4.5/../../../../lib/libhighgui.a(grfmt_jpeg2000.o): In function `cv::Jpeg2KEncoder::writeComponent16u(void*, cv::Mat const&)':
```

...
is because you have not installed the "Jasper" library or not installed correctly that your linker can not find the lib to link, try to install it and make sure the linker can find them, add -L/path/to/your/jasperlib/ option to your linker if necessary and don't forget the "-l" option.

The reason for the following errors are similar because the linker can not work without "zlib" and "BLAS/LAPACK" library.

Answer (score 0):

these linker errors:

```
/usr/include/boost/system/error_code.hpp:208: undefined reference to `boost::system::get_system_category()'
/usr/include/boost/system/error_code.hpp:209: undefined reference to `boost::system::get_generic_category()'
/usr/include/boost/system/error_code.hpp:214: undefined reference to `boost::system::get_generic_category()'
/usr/include/boost/system/error_code.hpp:215: undefined reference to `boost::system::get_generic_category()'
/usr/include/boost/system/error_code.hpp:216: undefined reference to `boost::system::get_system_category()'
```

mean you need to to link to the [Boost.System](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_0/libs/system/doc/index.html) library. I don't know how to do this using Eclipse, but using gcc I would add the following to my link line:

```
-Wl,-rpath,/path/to/boost -L/path/to/boost -lboost_system
```

You probably just need to instruct Eclipse to link to `-lboost_system` like you already have for

```
-lboost_iostreams -lboost_date_time -lboost_regex -lboost_thread -lboost_filesystem
```